# user32.dll keybd_event not working on windows service C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, user32

I created a windows service that writes a text when it receives it

Debugging the service works, but when I already install it it doesn't work.

This is my code

```
public static class KeyboardSimulator
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void keybd_event(uint bVk, uint bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);

        public enum win32Key : uint
        {
            [Description("0")] VK_KEY_0 = (uint)0x30,
            [Description("1")] VK_KEY_1 = (uint)0x31,
            [Description("2")] VK_KEY_2 = (uint)0x32,
            [Description("3")] VK_KEY_3 = (uint)0x33,
            [Description("4")] VK_KEY_4 = (uint)0x34,
            [Description("5")] VK_KEY_5 = (uint)0x35,
            [Description("6")] VK_KEY_6 = (uint)0x36,
            [Description("7")] VK_KEY_7 = (uint)0x37,
            [Description("8")] VK_KEY_8 = (uint)0x38,
            [Description("9")] VK_KEY_9 = (uint)0x39,
            [Description("A")] VK_KEY_A = (uint)0x41,
            [Description("B")] VK_KEY_B = (uint)0x42,
            [Description("C")] VK_KEY_C = (uint)0x43,
            [Description("D")] VK_KEY_D = (uint)0x44,
            [Description("E")] VK_KEY_E = (uint)0x45,
            [Description("F")] VK_KEY_F = (uint)0x46,
            [Description("G")] VK_KEY_G = (uint)0x47,
            [Description("H")] VK_KEY_H = (uint)0x48,
            [Description("I")] VK_KEY_I = (uint)0x49,
            [Description("J")] VK_KEY_J = (uint)0x4A,
            [Description("K")] VK_KEY_K = (uint)0x4B,
            [Description("L")] VK_KEY_L = (uint)0x4C,
            [Description("M")] VK_KEY_M = (uint)0x4D,
            [Description("N")] VK_KEY_N = (uint)0x4E,
            [Description("O")] VK_KEY_O = (uint)0x4F,
            [Description("P")] VK_KEY_P = (uint)0x50,
            [Description("Q")] VK_KEY_Q = (uint)0x51,
            [Description("R")] VK_KEY_R = (uint)0x52,
            [Description("S")] VK_KEY_S = (uint)0x53,
            [Description("T")] VK_KEY_T = (uint)0x54,
            [Description("U")] VK_KEY_U = (uint)0x55,
            [Description("V")] VK_KEY_V = (uint)0x56,
            [Description("W")] VK_KEY_W = (uint)0x57,
            [Description("X")] VK_KEY_X = (uint)0x58,
            [Description("Y")] VK_KEY_Y = (uint)0x59,
            [Description("Z")] VK_KEY_Z = (uint)0x5A,
            [Description("ENTER")] VK_RETURN = (uint)0x0D,
            [Description("TAB")] VK_TAB = (uint)0x09
        }

        public static uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDED_KEY = 0x1;
        public static uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;

        public static uint GetKey(string _description)
        {
            foreach (var _field in typeof(win32Key).GetFields())
            {
                if (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(_field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) is DescriptionAttribute _attribute)
                {
                    if (_attribute.Description == _description)
                    {
                        return (uint)_field.GetValue(null);
                    }
                    else if (_field.Name == _description)
                    {
                        return (uint)_field.GetValue(null);
                    }
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }

        public static void Write(string _message)
        {
            foreach (char _char in _message)
            {
                uint _key = GetKey($"{_char}");
                keybd_event(_key, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDED_KEY, 0);
                keybd_event(_key, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDED_KEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }
```

What I need is for the service to be running normally and write to any application that is active.

For example: if I'm in the notepad, write on it or if I'm on a web page, write on it.

Comment: The documentation for [keybd_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) says that it is superceded, and you should use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead. Note restrictions on integrity levels, UIPI, and properly manifesting your exe.